# Python Syntax Error on escaping slashes

Tags: macos, python-2.7, python-3.4

I am a bit confused as to why I am getting a syntax error on a simple variable assignment.

The code up to that point is:

```
import time
import os
import Quartz 

#constants
varcmd = "/usr/local/bin/python3"
```

The error message I am getting is:

```
File "/usr/local/bin/python27script.py", line 20
varcmd = "/usr/local/bin/python3"
         ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I have tried the following with no luck.

1. `varcmd = "/usr/local/bin/python3"`
2. `varcmd = '/usr/local/bin/python3'`
3. `varcmd = r"/usr/local/bin/python3"`
4. `varcmd = r'usr/local/bin/python3'`
5. `varcmd = "//usr//local//bin//python3"`
6. `varcmd = '//usr//local//bin//python3'`

This is running on OSX 10.11

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Check the line before that one

Comment: There is nothing before this one other than import statements.   When I comment out this line, it does not throw an error.

Comment: Maybe it's something to do with mixing tabs and spaces. Can you post some code before that line?

Comment: There's nothing special about *forward* slashes that you'd need to worry about. Show your full code, otherwise we can't help you a lot.

Comment: I have updated the code above.  When I comment out the varcmd line, it does not throw a syntax error.

Comment: Your quote may not be a standard ASCII double quote, but some smart type of quote. Double check your quotes, and the editor you're using.

Comment: I tried double quotes and single quotes.  Both seem to be a problem.  I am using TextEdit on OS X 10.11.  Could that be causing a problem?

Comment: Well, does it insert *smart quotes*? Curly quotes? Or are they straight? Either way, TextEdit isn't really a programmer's text editor; try TextWrangler, Sublime, TextMate or whatever other *programmer* text editor.

Comment: Try writing the same code, without copying and pasting, using a different text editor. Ideally one mentioned by @deceze above

Comment: I just tried it with TextWrangler and you guys are right.  TextEdit was causing the problem.

Comment: It should be this **varcmd = (r'usr\local\bin\python3')**  try this line hope so it will work .